# Modify web.config in Sharepoint based application

Tags: development, asp.net

Can i modify programmatically the web.config file of a Sharepoint 2010 site  in my custom application?

In devopment enviroment i add my custom config to web.config. Threre is a way to do this from my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class.[Here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-web-application-settings-web-config-modifications-in-sharepoint-2010-via-code) you can find good article about it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The essential part of this post - use SPWebConfigModification. Links are provided for reference only.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove anything from web.config if this not a developer environment? You can use xml-transform.

Comment: I want to add configuration for httpModule

Comment: How? Add some details. This answer is not useful.

Comment: I need to add a new line like <add name="StartUpModule" type="MyHttpModule" /> to web.config.